# How to find only numeric values without mix of alphabet values using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, match

I have one equation: `+8x2+10y2-99+5=99`.
I need separate the numeric values only without mix of alphabetic characters.
I used the regex `str.match(/[0-9]/g)` to get the all numeric values, but for the equation above, the results should be `-99,5,99`.

Comment: You set a bounty for this question, but is your real intention to get *an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources*? You have got 2 answers that are already credible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riffing on your original approach, we can build up to a solid solution and learn a little about how some additional regex features work.

First, let's add support for separating the alphabets.  That can be done by using the `\b` metacharacter, which gives a *virtual match* only at the transition point between a word character and a non-word character (or a word character and the beginning or end of the input text).  The definition of what constitutes a word character differs between regex implementations, but it's often *similar* to the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`; check your language reference documentation for the details.

```js
var results = '+8x2+10y2-99+5=99'.match(/\b[0-9]+\b/g);

document.writeln('<pre>' + results.join(',') + '</pre>');
```

This produces the following output, which is very close, but fails to pick up the '-':

```
99,5,99
```

Next stop: get the dash.  This is only a single character change, and we add the '-' character at the end of the [0-9] character class.  The '-' has special powers in a character class, which requires either escaping the '-' or using the special rule that it has no powers at the end of the character class; I don't like escaping when I don't have to, so at the end it goes.  Now for the example:

```js
var results = '+8x2+10y2-99+5=99'.match(/\b[0-9-]+\b/g);

document.writeln('<pre>' + results.join(',') + '</pre>');
```

And viola!  The results are in and they are good:

```
-99,5,99
```

However, we can improve on this regex.  The first improvement is to use the `\d` metacharacter to replace the way-too-long 0-9 range in the character class.  Using this technique represents a 33.333% savings in keys typed, and will impress your friends, colleagues, and regex wonks everywhere:

```js
var results = '+8x2+10y2-99+5=99'.match(/\b[\d-]+\b/g);

document.writeln('<pre>' + results.join(',') + '</pre>');
```

Just checking, and yes, we have the same results:

```
-99,5,99
```

Finally, we'll fix a little niggling issue that we created when we added the '-' support a couple of steps back.  The issue is that this approach can actually result in some false (or improper) match results.

For example, when the input contains a valid number minus another valid number, the previous solutions would return them both as one single result.  We'll test that and then separate the '-' to be matched only as a prefix to a valid number.  To test this, we have to change up the input just a bit (change the "10y2" to just "10") and then test the previous ("bad") and new ("good") solutions:

```js
var text = '+8x2+10-99+5=99';

var bad_results = text.match(/\b[\d-]+\b/g);
var good_results = text.match(/\b-?\d+\b/g);

document.writeln('<pre> Bad: ' + bad_results.join(',') + '</pre>');
document.writeln('<pre> Good: ' + good_results.join(',') + '</pre>');
```

The result from this is:

```
Bad: 10-99,5,99
Good: 10,-99,5,99
```

Clearly, this is a better approach.  And with that, we have our final solution.  Be well and regex wisely!

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 8):

You can use an optional hyphen and [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to match only numbers from given expressions:

```js
var str = '+8x2+10y2-99+5=99';

var matches = str.match(/-?\b\d+\b/g);

document.writeln('<pre>' + matches.join(',') + '</pre>');
```

**Output:**

```
-99,5,99
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ2rG9/2)